# Перебор в цикле функций с похожими именами

Tags: циклы, c++, visual-c++

Имеется куча функций

```
int func001();
int func002();
...
int func015();
...
int func123();
```

Как их всех можно перебрать в цикле?
Как вызвать функцию зная ее номер?

**P.S.** Убрал не работающий код.

Comment: а я не уверен, что Ваш код даже с нулями заработает.

Comment: Не заработает.

Comment: Если эти функции сделать экспортируемыми, то потом через GetProcAddress можно по имени получить указатель на функцию. А текстовое имя можно уже сгенерировать привычными способами.

Comment: Да, не заработает :(, но идея была через макросы "как-нибудь так".

Comment: Я думаю можно эти вызовы как-то нагенерить через Template Metaprogramming, если уж по хардкору угорать.

Comment: Вы вообще понимаете суть препроцессора? Он работает __ДО__ компилятора и заменяет вхождения задефайненых строк, рассматриваея код вашей програмы как обычный текст. То, что вы собираетесь перебирать переменную в цикле препроцессору неизвестно. Ваше `FUNC(i)` он заменил бы на `funci()`.

Comment: И я о том же

    Не заработает.

даже если исправить ошибку в #define (уже удаленном. Там вторые ## лишние).

--

В принципе можно, конечно, если потренироваться охота и не в препроцессоре.  Сделать из этого кода .so, загрузить его dlopen(), потом генерить символьные имена (sprintf() в цикле), доставать адрес через dlsym() и вызывать.

Comment: @Ildik Simpson, расскажите, откуда у вас столько функций с похожими названиями и зачем их всех вызывать? Может, можно как-то по-людски сделать?

Comment: Еще вариант. Даже если они `static`, но исполнимый модуль не "стрипнут". 

Можно анализировать свою таблицу символов (по сути вывод `popen(av[0], "r")`) и вызывать, когда встретится подходящее имя.

Comment: @fori1ton есть задачи, реализованные и выглядят они так:

    problem001.h problem001.cpp
    ....
    problem123.h problem123.cpp

в как полагается, в problemXXX.h - прототипы функций

    int solution001();  // вызывается функция с авторским решением и возвращает ответ
    int answer001();    // ответ на задачу
    string info001();   // условие задачи

И хотелось бы иметь такую возможность, чтобы, например, взять и записать в файл условие задачи и ниже ее ответ (или просто условия), причем со случайной выборкой. Реализация, конечно, не самая лучшая.

Comment: Ну так сделайте предварительную обработку исходного кода и генерацию нужной функции `main`, делов-то. Почему обязательно runtime и reflection?

Comment: Это однозначно надо решать, создавая shared library (.so или .dll в винде).

Делаете такую библиотеку. main при запуске подгружает ее и вызывает функции по имени, в зависимости от номера задачи.

Comment: @avp: Можно ж проще: написать отдельный скрипт, который обойдёт список файлов и создаст исходник с вызовами функций, разве нет? Тем более, имя файла напрямую отображается на имя функции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd), опять комментарии кончились, причем предыдущий удалил (хорошо, что  скопировал),
а новый не дает создать. Пришлось в ответе набивать...

Это однозначно надо решать, создавая shared library (.so или .dll в винде).

Делаете такую библиотеку. main при запуске подгружает ее и вызывает функции по имени, в зависимости от номера задачи.

--

Конечно, можно генерить исходник main-а по шаблону каждый раз.

Но, IMHO с загружаемой библиотекой (или несколькими) и файлом конфигурации к ним, описывающим аргументы-результат (предполагая некое развитие задачки) просто красивей.

Answer (score 3):

Создайте массив указателей на ваши функции, и вызывайте функции при проходе по массиву.

Но честно говоря очень, оочень странная задача как для C++.

**UPD**

Еще вариант: написать скрипт на Perl который сгенерит большой source file с вызовом всех этих функций.

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так.

```
#include <map>

void func1();
void func2();

int main()
{
     std::map<int, func_t> funcs;
     funcs.insert(std::make_pair(1, &func1));
     funcs.insert(std::make_pair(2, &func2));
     for(std::map<int, func_t>::iterator i = funcs.begin(); i != funcs.end(); i++) {
     { 
         i->second(/*аргументы*/);
     }
}
```

Comment: Да, все верно, но скорее всего вопрощающего интересует как "автоматизировать" процесс и не записывать руками все эти функции)

Comment: Отличное решение! Ведь это так классно - вручную пихать в map все 123 функции!

Comment: ну ТС спросил как их перебрать :) хотя, скорее всего, Вы правы.

Comment: @Макс Жуков, а чем Ваш способ (кроме количества набиваемых буковок) отличается от варианта @1101_debian (массив функций)?

Comment: большей универсальность видимо. Так как в нем ключи могут быть строковыми.

Comment: @avp, я не прочитал предыдущий ответ когда писал код) пусть как пример висит.